# Problem with changing the site language of the STS project of the IdentityServer4.Admin (Skoruba's Project)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to secure my asp.net core 3.1 web apps using Identity Server 4 (the popular OpenID Connect and OAuth Framework). I downloaded Skoruba's IdentityServer4 project and I'm trying to change the default culture of it, but I'm having problems.
The default culture code of this project is "en" and all of the outputs (labels, error messages, titles, views, ...) in this project are in English. I want to change those outputs to Persian and change the site's language to Persian.

You can see the source of the project at [here](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin).

I changed some files of the project like below. The `appsettings.js` file:

```
"CultureConfiguration": {
  "Cultures": [ "en", "fa", "fr", "ru", "sv", "zh", "da", "fi" ],
  "DefaultCulture": "fa"
}
```

The `CultureConfiguration` class:

```
public class CultureConfiguration
{
    public static readonly string[] AvailableCultures = { "en", "fa", "fr", "ru", "sv", "zh", "da", "fi" };
    public static readonly string DefaultRequestCulture = "fa";

    public List<string> Cultures { get; set; }
    public string DefaultCulture { get; set; } = DefaultRequestCulture;
}
```

And finally, in its `StartupHelpers` class I changed the body of `AddMvcWithLocalization` method as following:

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddMvcWithLocalization<TUser, TKey>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = ConfigurationConsts.ResourcesPath; });

    services.TryAddTransient(typeof(IGenericControllerLocalizer<>), typeof(GenericControllerLocalizer<>));

    var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews(o =>
        {
            o.Conventions.Add(new GenericControllerRouteConvention());
        })
        .AddViewLocalization(
            LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
            opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = ConfigurationConsts.ResourcesPath; })
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(m =>
        {
            m.FeatureProviders.Add(new GenericTypeControllerFeatureProvider<TUser, TKey>());
        });

    var cultureConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(CultureConfiguration)).Get<CultureConfiguration>();
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            // If cultures are specified in the configuration, use them (making sure they are among the available cultures),
            // otherwise use all the available cultures
            var supportedCultureCodes = (cultureConfiguration?.Cultures?.Count > 0 ?
                cultureConfiguration.Cultures.Intersect(CultureConfiguration.AvailableCultures) :
                CultureConfiguration.AvailableCultures).ToArray();

            if (!supportedCultureCodes.Any()) supportedCultureCodes = CultureConfiguration.AvailableCultures;
            var supportedCultures = supportedCultureCodes.Select(c => new CultureInfo(c)).ToList();

            // If the default culture is specified use it, otherwise use CultureConfiguration.DefaultRequestCulture ("en")
            var defaultCultureCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureConfiguration?.DefaultCulture) ?
                CultureConfiguration.DefaultRequestCulture : cultureConfiguration?.DefaultCulture;

            // If the default culture is not among the supported cultures, use the first supported culture as default
            if (!supportedCultureCodes.Contains(defaultCultureCode)) defaultCultureCode = supportedCultureCodes.FirstOrDefault();

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCultureCode);
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            //CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(supportedCultureCodes.First(c => c.Contains("fa")));
        });

    return mvcBuilder;
}
```

Actually, after this changes, the default culture code changed to "fa" but, those outputs are still showing in English instead of Persian.
Can anyone help me where my problem is or what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

We handled this by overriding default culture cookie in `HomeController`.
Put these codes on `HomeController` of both Admin and Identity projects.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConfigurationController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<ConfigurationController> logger) : base(logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request?.Cookies?.ContainsKey(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName) == false)
        {
            SetRequestCultureCookie(ConfigurationConsts.DefaultRequestCultureName);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        SetRequestCultureCookie(culture);

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }

    private void SetRequestCultureCookie(string cultureName)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cultureName)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );
    }
}
```

---

And add default language in constants

```
namespace Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Configuration.Constants
{
    public class ConfigurationConsts
    {
        ...
        ...
        public const string DefaultRequestCultureName = "fa";
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm gonna use the STS project only, then how can I do that? I don't want the user to see the changing language operation at the first request even! Where the corresponding cookie `.AspNetCore.Culture` didn't set on his browser yet.